# Stash's server.xml file can't be found

Tags: bitbucket-server

I want to change the Stash's port to 80 with steps following this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Changing+the+port+that+Stash+listens+on, but I can't find the shared folder, and also can't find the server.xml file,

I use Stash 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean `server.xml` in the `conf` directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @David: can you provide more path information for `conf`? From my own experiences with Stash, data/configuration/etc... are stored in two separate file trees.

Comment: @Brian: 'they' refers to Atlassian, not the poster of the question.